# How to use Visual Studio 2019 to target Windows 7?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7

I would like to use Visual Studio 2019 to enjoy the latest C++ additions, but targeting Windows 7.

I created a Windows C++ application using the VS 2019 wizard (running on Windows 10).

A `targetver.h` file is created by the wizard, with the following content:

```
#pragma once

// // Including SDKDDKVer.h defines the highest available Windows platform.
// If you wish to build your application for a previous Windows platform, include WinSDKVer.h and
// set the _WIN32_WINNT macro to the platform you wish to support before including SDKDDKVer.h.
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
```

I followed the instructions in the comment lines, and added the following lines in`targetver.h` (before the `#include <SDKDDKVer.h>` line):

```
// Target Windows 7 SP1
#include <WinSDKVer.h>
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601
```

To test that, in the program's main function I invoked an API ([`PathCchAppend`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/pathcch/nf-pathcch-pathcchappend)) that is *not* supported in Windows 7.

The program builds fine (I **statically link** the CRT), and runs fine in Windows 10.

The same program fails when executed in Windows 7, showing the following error message:

[image: Error message when trying to run the VS 2019 C++ application on Windows 7]

Now, the program should have **not compiled** at all, because I specified the Windows 7 target, and the aforementioned API is *not* available on Windows 7.

Is this a bug in the Windows SDK?

Is it possible to target Windows 7 using VS 2019 and the Windows 10 SDK, getting errors during the build process when an API or structure that is not supported in Windows 7 is used in the code, and how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual studio 2015 run-time dependencies or how to get rid of Universal CRT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805113/visual-studio-2015-run-time-dependencies-or-how-to-get-rid-of-universal-crt)

Comment: @dewaffled: I'll read the question you linked in details later, but if it's about static linking with the CRT, I already did that. To me, the code should not compile at all, as I tried to invoke an API that is not supported on Windows 7.

Comment: you try use api set (*api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0*) and api (*PathCchAppend*) which simply not exist in *win7*.

Comment: and no any conditional blocks in *pathcch.h* based on version selected. so compiled your code ok, build ok, but will be run only in win8+

Comment: @RbMm: So, what’s the point of #defining a preprocessor macro to explicitly target Windows 7? I thought I should get compile-time errors if I try to invoke APIs that are not available in Windows 7.

Comment: `PathCchAppend` was introduced in Windows 8. The header file it's declared in (`PathCch.h`) does not seem to have any tests for SDK versions at all, which is why your compile succeeds. Is this a bug in the SDK? I guess so.

Answer (score 1):

VS 2019's toolset and the latest Windows 10 SDK support targeting Windows 7 Service Pack 1.

You have already configured the Windows headers in the Windows 10 SDK properly:

```
#include <winsdkver.h>
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601
#include <sdkddkver.h>
```

You can still call APIs that are not supported by Windows 7 in this mode, which is why calling `PathCchAppend` builds, links, and fails at runtime.

The problem you are seeing may also be related to the Universal C/C++ Runtime not being on your target machine. Install the [x86](https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/VC_redist.x86.exe) and/or [x64 native](https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/VC_redist.x64.exe) version on your target test machine.

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/universal-crt-deployment).

Comment: I statically linked to the CRT. Should I still install additional DLLs on Windows 7? Can't I just deploy a single EXE built with VS 2019 and statically linked to the CRT?

Comment: In addition, I would expect a build failure, as I tried (on purpose) to invoke an API that is _not_ supported on Windows 7.

Comment: problem not related to crt - *api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0* (aka *kernelbase* ) and *PathCchAppend* not crt