# Can I use std::chrono on 2009 x86 Windows?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, c++20, c++-chrono

Is std::chrono available to use when running on a Windows 6.1.7601 x86 PC? (Windows 7 Professional, SP1).

I'm compiling in Visual Studio 2022 (on a new x64 PC) and don't care about other targets.

I just don't know if I'm doing it wrong, or if I'm just totally off base; when running, it goes straight to the "program.exe has stopped working" popup. The latest visual C++ x86 redistributable is installed on both the target and compilation computers.

My program is command-line only, and needs to access file last modified times and the current system time.

Comment: "~2009 Windows x86 PC" it doesn't matter what year your computer was purchased. What is important is what version of Windows it is running, and whether you targeted it properly in your project

Comment: @RaymondChen I glossed over the important part: Windows v6.1.7601.

Comment: @masher: That appears to be some form of Windows 7, which is no longer supported.

Comment: @NicolBolas very much so. The latest SDK https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/ does say that it supports Windows 7 SP1.

Comment: @masher: I also see the note "Not all tools are supported on earlier operating systems".

Comment: Windows 7 requires a special version of the CRT. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63874422/how-to-use-visual-studio-2019-to-target-windows-7