# Building executable in Visual Studio 2022 with "Release" configuration, built EXE asking for debug DLLs

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dll, compiler-errors

The EXE I'm building builds fine using Release config (x64). When ran on another computer it asks for both:

- ucrtbased.dll
- vcruntime140d.dll

From what I can tell, the program shouldn't be asking for these debug (denoted with "d" at the end of their filenames) DLL files.

I am researching this simultaneous to asking this question, but have a bit of a time crunch to figure this out. I'm looking for any common culprits, or things that I could be missing? Not the most versed on this WIN process.

---

If I source the missing DLLs and add them to the directory with the EXE, I get this error message:

- "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application."

The EXE works fine on my machine, where I co-developed the program. Does not work when we try to take it to another machine with a release package.

Comment: Have you changed the runtime library setting of any of your projects? Do you link to any libraries which maybe linked to the debug runtime?

Answer (score -2):

You need to check whether the library files are mixed with 32/64 bits versions.

vcruntime140.dll is [Visual C++ Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145).

In addition, the methods in this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805113/visual-studio-2015-run-time-dependencies-or-how-to-get-rid-of-universal-crt) are worthy of your reference.

Comment: You can't install the debug runtime via the redistributable, in fact you aren't allowed to redistribute the debug runtime