# LNK1104 cannot open file 'ucrtd.lib' in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

so i don't know a lot for VS2015
i downlode it because i want to use it in my University to use OpenGL
so i have this problem and i didn't fine any way to fix it

first of all i install the program in disk D: 
i have made a project in C and D and got the same problem 
i try to run it without debug and without cod

"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'ucrtd.lib'    ConsoleApplication2 D:\Users\Anmar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\LINK   1
"
this is photo for the problem when i add some code and run it
http://screencast.com/t/znmUrht6vyg

the code was

```
#include <glut.h>

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2f(-0.5, -0.5);
    glVertex2f(-0.5, 0.5);
    glVertex2f(0.5, 0.5);
    glVertex2f(0.5, -0.5);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

so any way to fix this ?

Answer (score 4):

I think your question may be similar to this one:

[How to I update my C++ project in Visual Studio 2015 to use the new Universal CRT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527969/how-to-i-update-my-c-project-in-visual-studio-2015-to-use-the-new-universal-cr)

I had to do a couple things to get older C++ projects to work with VS2015.

First, I had to make sure I installed MFC as part of VS2015.

Second, I needed to add to my LibraryPath, for my 32-bit project:

```
$(UniversalCRT_LibraryPath_x86)
```

So now my vcxproj file has this for its LibraryPath

```
<LibraryPath Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\lib\wxp\i386;$(VCInstallDir)lib;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\lib;$(WindowsSdkDir_71A)lib;$(UniversalCRT_LibraryPath_x86)</LibraryPath>
```

Third, I had to refresh my understanding of the variety of C Run-Time libraries with VS2015, since they have changed a little bit.  Here's the link to CRT Library Features on MSDN, which explains how all the switches affect what in VS2015:

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx
```

Some of my vcxproj switches were mismatched with what MSDN said.  It took a little effort to get them all straightened out.

Then I realized I had only done my Debug configuration.  I had to also make all the changes all over again to my Release configuration.  Good safety tip.

Hope that helps!