# VS 2017 cmake error

Tags: cmake

I am trying to build my code using 3d builder. Am using VS 2017 version. Previously it was working fine but after windows update while trying to open code using VS cmake compiler error. Hereby attaching the log files of error. Is anyone facing the same error? Could someone suggest a way to resolve it?

```
Build started 7/20/2018 6:39:28 PM.
Project "C:\code\dump64\CMakeFiles\3.8.20170425-g0257b-dirty\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "Debug\".
  Creating directory "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x64\CL.exe /c /nologo /W0 /WX- /diagnostics:classic /Od /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc141.pdb" /Gd /TP /FC /errorReport:queue CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
  CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
Link:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:".\CompilerIdCXX.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /PDB:".\CompilerIdCXX.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:".\CompilerIdCXX.lib" /MACHINE:X64 Debug\CMakeCXXCompilerId.obj
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ucrtd.lib' [C:\code\dump64\CMakeFiles\3.8.20170425-g0257b-dirty\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\code\dump64\CMakeFiles\3.8.20170425-g0257b-dirty\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
```

Comment: The problem seems to be related with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527969/how-to-i-update-my-c-project-in-visual-studio-2015-to-use-the-new-universal-cr. (Found by googling for `cannot open file 'ucrtd.lib'`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to I update my C++ project in Visual Studio 2015 to use the new Universal CRT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527969/how-to-i-update-my-c-project-in-visual-studio-2015-to-use-the-new-universal-cr)